# How to specify the key field for a trigger condition in Opensearch?

Tags: opensearch

I have a query that aggregates the results into buckets, using multi_term aggregation. I'm trying to build a trigger for one of the buckets.

Here is the current trigger:

```
{
    "buckets_path": {
        "_count": "_count"
    },
    "parent_bucket_path": "hot",
    "script": {
        "source": "params._count > 0",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

And here is the aggregation response:

```
    "aggregations": {
        "hot": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "term1|term2",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "key": [
                        "term1",
                        "term2"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the key returned in the query response is an array, which causes the following error when I run the trigger:

```
Unexpected format for key in bucket [{key_as_string=term1|term2, doc_count=2, key=[term1, term2]}]
```

In the query response, there is another key named *key_as_string*. How do I change the trigger condition to use *key_as_string* instead of *key*?